# Is a Function Argument a Native Element or a jQuery Set?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a general purpose helper function in JavaScript. It accesses the `className` property of the element.

But since I'm using jQuery, it turns out that sometimes the element passed as an argument is actually an array (a jQuery set).

What is the simplest way to use an argument if it's an element or get the first element from the set if the argument is a set? Does jQuery have a tool for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can test if the object is a jQuery object by using `instanceof`:

```
if (myObject instanceof jQuery) {
    // use $.each to loop over myObject and get class names of all
    // or just use myObject[0].className to return only the first
} else {
    // it's not a jQuery object
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You always want a native element? Each jQuery object has a property `jquery` (containing the jQuery version) so you can use it to check if the element you got is likely to be a jQuery object:

```
obj = obj.jquery ? obj[0] : obj;
```

If you are not into ducktyping:

```
obj = (obj instanceof jQuery) ? obj[0] : obj;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will fail if the argument is an element and not a set.

Comment: Updated. I think now that's what you want.

Comment: What does `obj.jquery` do?

Comment: @JonathanWood version of jQuery running, but I would use instanceof jQuery like jbabey suggests.

Comment: Updated the answer again. It contains the jQuery version and (usually) doesn't exist for native DOM objects

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to pass a single element, an array of elements or a jQuery object to the same method, do the following:

```
function stuff(element) {
    element = [].concat(element)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to deal with *both* jQuery objects and non-jQuery elements, this is a bit tougher.  Keep in mind that the jQuery collection can possibly have different `className`s for each element, i.e. the first and others may not be the same.

It's slightly inefficient, but this will work:

```
function (obj) {
   var className = $(obj).get(0).className;
}
```

Wrapping a jQuery object in `jQuery()` does nothing, but wrapping the element allows you to access it again via `.get`.  It's inefficient because you may have an extra `$()` call.

If that's no good, you could check `obj.hasOwnProperty('className')` since a jQuery object *usually* should not have it, but I think that is riskier.

Answer (score 0):

> Is a jQuery Object an Element or an Array of Elements?

Strictly, neither.

A jQuery object is a Javascript object that has some of the Array capabilities. In most aspects you can use it as an array of elements.

---

If the jQuery object may contain several elements, and you only want the first, you can use the [`first` method](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to get that:

```
elements = elements.first();
```

If the parameter can be either an element, an array of elements, or a jQuery object, you can wrap it in a jQuery object to handle all the cases:

```
elements = $(elements).first();
```